# Fetching System IP address in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone suggest a solution for emulator to get my own local IP (not 
10.0.2.15)? But i want to get my actual IP of my system. Is there any 
solution to it?

Comment: see this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is using a private network, which you already found out, however you can fire an intent to get your public IP address

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH -e query "what is my ip"
```

Running this is the emulator's shell will open the Browser and show you your public IP address.

Comment: Thank you for relying. Can you please elaborate your answer little more, since we are new to android we are not so clear