# Generate a PC ID (No need to be Unique + Doesn't require Admin)

Tags: c#

I am making a WCF application, and I just want to have some extra info on the user connected to server. It doesn't have to be a Unique ID.

I really want something simple. Would this work ?

```
static UserInfo() // d-constructor
        {

            MachineID = Environment.MachineName;
            MachineID = MachineID + Convert.ToString(Environment.OSVersion);
            MachineID = MachineID + Environment.ProcessorCount;
            MachineID = MachineID + Environment.UserName;
            MachineID = MachineID + Environment.Version;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: @erikkallen I am not asking if the actual code works or not. What i'm asking is if I am using the right way to achieve this. Maybe there is some other class (beside Enviroment) ?

Comment: The only question mark in your question is after the phrase "Would this work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that would work.  I checked in in LINQPad 4 quickly, and it came back fine:

> MYMACHINEMicrosoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 14myuser4.0.30319.296

You might consider replacing spaces with underscores or something like that if you want the string to be free of spaces - maybe...

```
MachineID = MachineID.Replace(' ', '_');
```

...added to the end of your `UserInfo()` method.

**UPDATE:**

To follow comments below, [Windows 7 Help Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/164915-run-different-user-shortcut-create-specified-program-user.html) has quick steps to make a shortcut to run a command as a specific user: to test I setup a shortcut to run `cmd.exe` as non-admin user `myuser`, which I created for the purpose.  Again, my test here was to then run `set` and `systeminfo` from the command line as `myuser` - testing by analogy but I think sufficient.

**UPDATE:**

To follow further, I created another shortcut to run LINQPad 4 as non-admin user `myuser`, then re-run the code: no problemo tested this way too.  I aim to please. :)

Comment: So it doesn't need for any admin privilege? I think only the MachineName and Processorcount has a higher rate of being unique, right? Is there any other Class that I can get more info?

Comment: I just double checked the possibility of needing admin permissions: nope, all good as a non-admin user.  This makes sense because in command-line terms, you are really just getting info that `set` and `systeminfo` provide.  Now maybe a policy (e.g. in an AD domain) could snag running as a non-admin; but running as a non-admin user doesn't itself present a problem getting the environment info you specified.

Comment: I don't know that `ProcessorCount` is going to add much, unless you are handling requests from machines that may have name collisions (e.g. > 1 machine being named MYMACHINE).  IP address may be worth considering, but it really depends on your use-case.  `MachineName` and `UserName` should really get most of the way to what you want (i.e. "(No need to be Unique + Doesn't require Admin)").

Comment: Thank you so much. and +1 on that Replace thing. As a beginner, I had no idea you could replace a character in 1 single line. I was thinking about hashing that string, that's why i ignored the spaces. btw, Do you know any other info which can be gathered as well? mac address, motherboard id,or...

Comment: Not a problem.  Hashing crossed my mind as well, but I wanted to stay on the critical path outlined in your question. :)  For additional/different things that you think you might like to include in your machine-user ID, quick searches like "C# MAC address", "C# <whatever>" at SO, Bing, or Google should lead you quickly to code you can absorb into yours.  Bing actually listed [an SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/850650/1810429) regarding MAC address that would help with that.