# Getting Mac Address for all Network Cards even if NIC is Disabled in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get all NICs Mac addresses

I am using this Code in java script

```
select * from win32_networkadapterconfiguration
```

I am having 2 Connected NICs (LAN, Wireless)

It Works Fine but when i disable the Wireless card i didn't get its MAC Address.

Is it possible to get its's mac address even if it is disabled?

Comment: The answer is With `javascript` or 'jquery', No my friend...

Comment: Can i get it with any other way???

Comment: Yeah you must have to use an `ActiveX` control for that as you are using `C#`...

Comment: can you help me with that and give me the solution?

Comment: You could try this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp