# Is there a way to identify the device Horizon view is on

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a program in C# that I have been using for quite a few years for tracking user activity and collecting information if and where students are using our software.  Now part of our School is slowly switching to DELL Wyse Zero Client units (P25).  So 1/2 of or VM are on Wyse units and the other half auto boot to the horizon view client on boot. On the client side, When the user logsin, is there a way for the VM to read and report either the MAC address, or machine name of the Wyse unit, or workstation the Horizon View Client is running on through the VM.

Thanks
     Dave.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking just to get the Machine name you can use Enviornment.MachineName

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp) answers how to get a MAC address with C#

Comment: I need more than the machine name.  (The method you mentioned is what I use now)  The machine name will just tell me the name of the VM.  Not the device the user is logged into.  With the Device name or MAK address of the device I can tell which room and whether or not they coming in outside the school.

Comment: Is it a thin client or a zero client that the users are using to connect?

Comment: The Wyse units are zero client (P25's) and the workstations are using windows xp 64 bit to for the workstation and auto load the Horizon View Client.

Comment: You could write a script that grabs the machine name before the client is launched then use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path to horizon client") to get the information you're looking for then. But to my knowledge there is no way to get the host machines MAC/Name from inside the Horizon enviornment.  Edit: Also, change the icon to the horizon icon to not confuse users.

Comment: Unless i misread what you said and it's connecting to an XP machine, in which case I don't know how to help

Comment: Also, check [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1344dad4-dffe-486c-bf30-1b75d21fc9ba/get-mac-address-of-client-machine-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom) for information of getting mac addresses for client machines

Comment: my comments on the XP workstation.  That is the os that boots on the physical workstation it then launches the horizon client and the user loggs into their VM which is Windows 7.  I use XP because it has a much smaller foot print.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  In the registry of to VM (windows 7) under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Volatile Environment are a number of keys that give information on the device that is hosting the Horizon View Client.
 The ones I am interested in is.
ViewClient_Machine_Name
ViewClient_IP_Address
ViewClient_MAC_Address
and much more.
Thanks
     Dave