# In C# how to find the mac address of internal devices not the Router mac address

Tags: c#

I want to get the mac address of my software user on the network due to some security reasons. But i am able to get the mac address of the router through following method.

```
public string GetMACAddress()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        String sMacAddress = string.Empty;
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
        {
            if (sMacAddress == String.Empty)// only return MAC Address from first card  
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                sMacAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            }
        } return sMacAddress;
    }
```

I need the specific mac address of the system that access my software on the internet and the internal device of that router. is that possible through C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is the best way to get Mac address of your User.

```
[DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
        private static extern int SendARP(Int32 dest, Int32 host, ref Int64 mac, ref Int32 length);
        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")]
        private static extern Int32 inet_addr(string ip);
        private static string GetClientMAC(string strClientIP)
        {
            string mac_dest = "";
            try
            {
                Int32 ldest = inet_addr(strClientIP);
                Int32 lhost = inet_addr("");
                Int64 macinfo = new Int64();
                Int32 len = 6;
                int res = SendARP(ldest, 0, ref macinfo, ref len);
                string mac_src = macinfo.ToString("X");

                while (mac_src.Length < 12)
                {
                    mac_src = mac_src.Insert(0, "0");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == (i % 2))
                    {
                        if (i == 10)
                        {
                            mac_dest = mac_dest.Insert(0, mac_src.Substring(i, 2));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mac_dest = "-" + mac_dest.Insert(0, mac_src.Substring(i, 2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw new Exception("Lỗi " + err.Message);
            }
            return mac_dest;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This Works for me.!

```
string macAddress = NetworkInterface
.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
.Where( nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback )
.Select( nic => nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString() )
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp#comment15830009_7661829

Comment: thanks @Mihir but this string get the mac address of my router. but i need the mac address of the internal devices of that router.

Comment: so can you please explain what do you mean by "the internal devices of that router" are you running your c# code on router?

Answer (score 1):

```
static string GetMacAddress()
{
    string macAddresses = "";
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
        // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces, thereby ignoring any
        // loopback devices etc.
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) continue;
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up) {
            macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return macAddresses;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.independent-software.com/get-local-machines-mac-address-in-c/), just one quick google away.