# Log Windows version and Machine ID with Nlog

Tags: c#, windows, logging, nlog, mac-address

Is there a way to log the Windows version and the MAC address (or some other type of unique machine ID) using Nlog in C#? The logger would be running on windows desktop PCs.

Comment: If you can _get_ both in a C# program, you can _log_ both, yes. Or do you mean in a layout renderer?

Comment: See [Environment.OSVersion Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?view=netcore-3.1), [Reliable method to get machine's MAC address in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/850650/982149)

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the info. I was curious how I may add that info (Windows version and MAC address) in the layout renderer.

Answer (score 4):

Nlog has some [layout renderers](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers) you can try:

> - [${environment}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-Layout-Renderer) - The environment variable. (e.g PATH, OSVersion)
> - [${machinename}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MachineName-Layout-Renderer) - The machine name that the process is running on.
> - [${hostname}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/HostName-Layout-Renderer) - The host name of the computer that the process is running on.

You can add them to `layout=` attribute of corresponding target.